# Sharepoint workflow performance Issue

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I don't have experience with sharepoint developments, I was asked to have a look at a workflow performance.
After some tracing, i found which part takes too much time to execute:

```
using (var site = new SPSite(WorkflowWeb.Site.ID, workflowProperties.OriginatorUser.UserToken))
        {
            using (var web = site.OpenWeb(WorkflowWeb.ServerRelativeUrl))
            {
                var list = web.Lists[WorkflowItem.ParentList.ID];
                var item = list.Items[WorkflowItem.UniqueId];


                item[new Guid("{54GH32R2-HG66-654a-KKKK-456FFF864654}")] = SPUtility.GetLocalizedString("$Resources:Assigned_Car", "RealB", WorkflowWeb.Language);
                item[new Guid("{54FG6215-9584-123g-KJHG-456FFF864654}")] = DateTime.Now;
                item.Update();
            }
        }
```

This part takes around 5 min to execute. Any tip to improve the performance?

As I mentioned, I have no SP experience, I also don't have much knowledge of what the workflow is doing, I just have to solve it quick and dirty.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow It's now faster by changing:

```
var item = list.Items[WorkflowItem.UniqueId];
```

To

```
var item = list.GetItemByUniqueId(WorkflowItem.UniqueId);
```

Answer (score 0):

Under normal circumstances the presented piece of code **cannot** take 5 minutes to execute. Performace-wise, to execute this code, even when a previously not cached `SPSite` needs to be opened, is a sub-second matter.

What *does* take up to 5 minutes in SharePoint 2010 with default configuration of `owstimer` (the process executing workflows asynchronously) is the delay between workflow engine invocations which in turn execute workflows. Depending on the way you measure the 'performance' ('run-time duration' would be a much better term to use here) of the workflow this idle time may be included in your results.

---

*Side note:*

> I have no SP experience, I also don't have much knowledge of what the workflow is doing, I just have to solve it quick and dirty.

*Then it's a very bad idea to tacked with SharePoint beyond basic learning tasks. Performance tuning and troubleshooting definitely **are not** tasks suitable for people with a complete lack of knowledge and experience with the platform. SharePoint is a very complex platform and its behaviour is, sometimes, far from straightforward. You should learn and earn experience with SharePoint on something much less complicated.*

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer my question.
My aim is not to learn the platform or gain experience, it's just one time request from a friend to help him to improve the performance. but as you mentioned, i maybe have to first find which line has the issue and investigate further. thanks again.

Comment: *How* did you measure performance of the workflow? Using an external performance profiler tool would be the best option.